# Obiee doesn't showing the actual data

Tags: oracle, obiee

We use OBIEE 12c, and this month we discovered that no records for this month has been fetched by OBIEE. That is, in database we have records for this dates, however when we create analyses in OBIEE to some particular day of this month, it says 'No Results'. What could be the reason?

I tried to clear the cache by setting `SET VARIABLE DISABLE_CACHE_HIT=1;`
and by checking the box

> Bypass Oracle BI Presentation Services Cache

However, the result did not change.
Have someone faced the same issue?

P.S. The query in the logs:

```
WITH 
SAWITH0 AS (select sum(T24270.SALDO_OUT_EQV) as c1,
     T23805.CAL_DAY as c2,
     T23805.CAL_MONTH as c3,
     T24021.CODE as c4
from 
     DM_FILIALS_V T24021 /* D4 Filials */ ,
     DM_CALENDAR_V T23805 /* D3 Calendar */ ,
     DM_COA_SALDO_V T24270 /* F4 Coa Saldo */ 
where  ( T23805.CAL_DAY = T24270.OPER_DAY and T23805.CAL_DAY = TO_DATE('2018-03-07' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') and T24021.CODE = T24270.FILIAL_CODE and T24270.OPER_DAY = TO_DATE('2018-03-07' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') ) 
group by T23805.CAL_DAY, T23805.CAL_MONTH, T24021.CODE)
select D1.c1 as c1, D1.c2 as c2, D1.c3 as c3, D1.c4 as c4, D1.c5 as c5 from ( select 0 as c1,
     D1.c2 as c2,
     D1.c3 as c3,
     D1.c4 as c4,
     D1.c1 as c5
from 
     SAWITH0 D1
order by c2, c4, c3 ) D1 where rownum <= 65001
```

I executed the above query with minor changes, removed 'SAWith0 As'

```
select sum(T24270.SALDO_OUT_EQV) as c1,
     T23805.CAL_DAY as c2,
     T23805.CAL_MONTH as c3,
     T24021.CODE as c4
from 
     DM_FILIALS_V T24021 /* D4 Filials */ ,
     DM_CALENDAR_V T23805 /* D3 Calendar */ ,
     DM_COA_SALDO_V T24270 /* F4 Coa Saldo */ 
where  ( T23805.CAL_DAY = T24270.OPER_DAY and T23805.CAL_DAY = TO_DATE('2018-03-07' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') and T24021.CODE = T24270.FILIAL_CODE and T24270.OPER_DAY = TO_DATE('2018-03-07' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') ) 
group by T23805.CAL_DAY, T23805.CAL_MONTH, T24021.CODE;
------
select D1.c1 as c1, D1.c2 as c2, D1.c3 as c3, D1.c4 as c4, D1.c5 as c5 from ( select 0 as c1,
     D1.c2 as c2,
     D1.c3 as c3,
     D1.c4 as c4,
     D1.c1 as c5
from 
     (select sum(T24270.SALDO_OUT_EQV) as c1,
     T23805.CAL_DAY as c2,
     T23805.CAL_MONTH as c3,
     T24021.CODE as c4
from 
     DM_FILIALS_V T24021 /* D4 Filials */ ,
     DM_CALENDAR_V T23805 /* D3 Calendar */ ,
     DM_COA_SALDO_V T24270 /* F4 Coa Saldo */ 
where  ( T23805.CAL_DAY = T24270.OPER_DAY and T23805.CAL_DAY = TO_DATE('2018-03-07' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') and T24021.CODE = T24270.FILIAL_CODE and T24270.OPER_DAY = TO_DATE('2018-03-07' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') ) 
group by T23805.CAL_DAY, T23805.CAL_MONTH, T24021.CODE) D1
order by c2, c4, c3 ) D1 where rownum <= 65001
```

P.S.. Here is the log itself

```
[2018-07-04T11:28:25.662+05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: dc67a996-12ac-4c0e-8cc3-a1cb22001cab-000fe34e,0:1:9:3] [sik: ssi] [tid: 7d65e700] [messageid: USER-0] [requestid: 2dce0038] [sessionid: 2dce0000] [username: weblogic] ############################################## [[
-------------------- SQL Request, logical request hash:
e8ddd88f
SET VARIABLE QUERY_SRC_CD='Report';SELECT
   0 s_0,
   "Остатки счетов"."Календарь"."День" s_1,
   "Остатки счетов"."Календарь"."Месяц" s_2,
   "Остатки счетов"."Филиалы"."Код филиала" s_3,
   "Остатки счетов"."Остатки по бал. сч."."Исх. сальдо (экв.)" s_4
FROM "Остатки счетов"
WHERE
("Календарь"."День" = date '2018-03-07')
ORDER BY 2 ASC NULLS LAST, 4 ASC NULLS LAST, 3 ASC NULLS LAST
FETCH FIRST 65001 ROWS ONLY


]]
[2018-07-04T11:28:25.662+05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: dc67a996-12ac-4c0e-8cc3-a1cb22001cab-000fe34e,0:1:9:3] [sik: ssi] [tid: 7d65e700] [messageid: USER-23] [requestid: 2dce0038] [sessionid: 2dce0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- General Query Info: [[
Repository: ssi, Subject Area: Saldo, Presentation: Остатки счетов

]]
[2018-07-04T11:28:25.675+05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: dc67a996-12ac-4c0e-8cc3-a1cb22001cab-000fe34e,0:1:9:5] [sik: ssi] [tid: 7d65e700] [messageid: USER-18] [requestid: 2dce0038] [sessionid: 2dce0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Sending query to database named dwiabs (id: <<459822>>), connection pool named ibs conn pool, logical request hash e8ddd88f, physical request hash 77dd8ab4: [[
WITH 
SAWITH0 AS (select sum(T24270.SALDO_OUT_EQV) as c1,
     T23805.CAL_DAY as c2,
     T23805.CAL_MONTH as c3,
     T24021.CODE as c4
from 
     DM_FILIALS_V T24021 /* D4 Filials */ ,
     DM_CALENDAR_V T23805 /* D3 Calendar */ ,
     DM_COA_SALDO_V T24270 /* F4 Coa Saldo */ 
where  ( T23805.CAL_DAY = T24270.OPER_DAY and T23805.CAL_DAY = TO_DATE('2018-03-07' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') and T24021.CODE = T24270.FILIAL_CODE and T24270.OPER_DAY = TO_DATE('2018-03-07' , 'YYYY-MM-DD') ) 
group by T23805.CAL_DAY, T23805.CAL_MONTH, T24021.CODE)
select D1.c1 as c1, D1.c2 as c2, D1.c3 as c3, D1.c4 as c4, D1.c5 as c5 from ( select 0 as c1,
     D1.c2 as c2,
     D1.c3 as c3,
     D1.c4 as c4,
     D1.c1 as c5
from 
     SAWITH0 D1
order by c2, c4, c3 ) D1 where rownum <= 65001

]]
[2018-07-04T11:28:25.740+05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: dc67a996-12ac-4c0e-8cc3-a1cb22001cab-000fe34e,0:1:10] [sik: ssi] [tid: 7d65e700] [messageid: USER-34] [requestid: 2dce0038] [sessionid: 2dce0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Query Status: Successful Completion
[2018-07-04T11:28:25.740+05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: dc67a996-12ac-4c0e-8cc3-a1cb22001cab-000fe34e,0:1:10] [sik: ssi] [tid: 7d65e700] [messageid: USER-26] [requestid: 2dce0038] [sessionid: 2dce0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Rows 9, bytes 792 retrieved from database query id: <<459822>>, physical request hash 77dd8ab4
[2018-07-04T11:28:25.740+05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: dc67a996-12ac-4c0e-8cc3-a1cb22001cab-000fe34e,0:1:10] [sik: ssi] [tid: 7d65e700] [messageid: USER-28] [requestid: 2dce0038] [sessionid: 2dce0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Physical query response time 0.050 (seconds), id <<459822>>, physical request hash 77dd8ab4
[2018-07-04T11:28:25.740+05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: dc67a996-12ac-4c0e-8cc3-a1cb22001cab-000fe34e,0:1:10] [sik: ssi] [tid: 7d65e700] [messageid: USER-29] [requestid: 2dce0038] [sessionid: 2dce0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Physical Query Summary Stats: Number of physical queries 1, Cumulative time 0.050, DB-connect time 0.003 (seconds)
[2018-07-04T11:28:25.740+05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: dc67a996-12ac-4c0e-8cc3-a1cb22001cab-000fe34e,0:1:10] [sik: ssi] [tid: 7d65e700] [messageid: USER-24] [requestid: 2dce0038] [sessionid: 2dce0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Rows returned to Client 9
[2018-07-04T11:28:25.740+05:00] [OBIS] [TRACE:2] [] [] [ecid: dc67a996-12ac-4c0e-8cc3-a1cb22001cab-000fe34e,0:1:10] [sik: ssi] [tid: 7d65e700] [messageid: USER-33] [requestid: 2dce0038] [sessionid: 2dce0000] [username: weblogic] -------------------- Logical Query Summary Stats: Elapsed time 0.080, Total time in BI Server 0.079, Execution time 0.067, Response time 0.079, Compilation time 0.015 (seconds), logical request hash e8ddd88f
```

Comment: As "dates" have been mentioned: does the OBIEE query work with *dates*, or do you - by mistake - use *strings* instead? Those look like dates to you (and me), but Oracle might think different.

Comment: They are declared as date data type, and Oracle works correctly with like 30.06.2018 (June 30) and gets the data for that day, but when we want to see data for 03.07.2018 (July 3) we get nothing although the records exists and were validated by querying directly in database

Comment: "he records exists and were validated by querying directly in database" - So did you also look at the query logs? What does the logical query look like? What does the physical query look like?

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the logs and the query in it worked in database. I will insert it to the question now

Comment: Thanks. But what does the log say about the LOGICAL query before it gets transformed into a physical one?

Comment: just added the log to the question

Comment: Query looks perfectly normal to me. Seems to be a caching issue in the OBIPS.

Comment: Yes, query works, but how can I solve caching issue? Any ideas? In biinstance configuration, caching is disabled, so I have no idea what could be the reason